# How to get the removed branches in git

Tags: linux, git, git-svn

I merge my all of the branches to a wrong branch and deleted all of the branches.
Is it possible to recover all of these branch and unmerge them.
I also resolved conflict at the time of merging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tool like `gitk --all` to find the commits that your branches were at before the merge.

Once you've got the commit's SHA1s, you can re-create the branches with something like:

```
git checkout <the sha1> -b <the old branch name>
```

Or simply:

```
git branch <the old branch name> <the sha1>
```

Or right-click on the relevant commit in `gitk` and use the `Create new branch` menu.

Repeat for all your old branch names. The go back to your incorrectly merged branch and revert the merge commit, or use some history rewriting to make it "go away". (Be very careful with that second option, it's not a good idea if you've already published that merge.)

Comment: You can also just create the branches in gitk, by right-clicking on commits. And if you don't want to do that, you still don't need to check out - just use `git branch <name> <SHA1>`.